# Can I spin the minigun without firing bullets?

Tags: fallout-4

I own an Explosive Minigun, and anyone using Explosive guns can testify, shooting things at point blank range is rather bad for your well being.

Is there a way to spin up the minigun without shooting bullets?

Comment: You can "tap" the button for a short duration, release it and tap again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but getting the timing is fairly tricky. You simply press the trigger for just under a second, then release it, wait a short while, press again for a short while, release again, etc.

The barrels seem to spin down faster than they spin up, so hold the trigger for a slightly shorter time than you released it for.